# optaplanner dynamic allocation of equipment

Tags: optaplanner

In the optaplanner document, I did not see an example of a multi-equipment and multi-process scenario, my appeal is very simple
For example: there is a product with processes 10, 20, 30, and the equipment that can process 10 processes are M1, M2, M3, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4 and the equipment that can process 20 processes are M3, M4, M5 , The equipment that can process 30 processes is M6, M7, M8

Take process 10 as an example, if there are 2000 products to be processed, they cannot be allocated to a single M1, and a balance between multiple devices should be achieved.

Sorry, I didn’t find practical examples in the official documents. Now I don’t have any ideas at all. Can any kind person help to see this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLaxc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CloudBalancing and PAS (Hospital bed planning) examples in the docs and `optaplanner-examples`. It sounds like your problem aligns well with those.

Comment: the CloudBalancing and PAS (Hospital bed planning) examples can not help me，because my model is a factory producing products, multiple machines producing multiple products, and multiple machines producing multiple products

Comment: This problem has been bothering me for 2 months, I really have no choice, no idea at all

Comment: I sincerely hope that Geoffrey god can help me and give me some good suggestions